# Setting app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf on ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I thought only by using `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_proximity"` is enough to set the `ImageView` below `TextView`. Do I need to  use `marginTop` to have both `TextView` visible? Or am I missing any attribute? Why in this case constraint is not working?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_light"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_light"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_proximity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_proximity"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_proximity" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some Constraints here and there..

Replace your entire code with below code and your layout will work just fine..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_light"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/label_light"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_proximity"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/label_proximity"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_proximity" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please update here if it's working fine.

Comment: Please do not use constraintEnd and constraintStart , never ever, just contraintBottom and constraintTop , Left , Right will do. I just experienced one issue RecyclerView inside ConstraintLayout w/ ConstraintEnd/Start will having scroll till the end, ( display only half of last item ), on top of RecyclerView have a search bar